# Elastic search aggregation with range query

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, sense

I am working to build a ES query that satisfies the condition  >= avg .

Here is an example:

```
GET /_search
{
    "size" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "price": {
                        "gte": {
                          "aggs" : {
                            "single_avg_price": {
                                "avg" :{ 
                                  "field" : "price" 
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
"type": "query_parsing_exception",
"reason": "[range] query does not support [aggs]",
```

I wonder how do we use aggregated value with range query in Elastic query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried using different ES aggregations such as [bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) , I found that it can be done using python.

Here is the python code I created to solve this issue.
Please note: URL , USER_NAME , PASSWORD needs to be filled before run it.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys,json,requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# static variables
URL=''
USER_NAME=''
PASSWORD=''

# returns avg value 
def getAvg():
    query = json.dumps({
        "aggs": {
            "single_avg_price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
         }
    })
    response = requests.get(URL,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER_NAME,PASSWORD), data=query)
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    return results['aggregations']['single_avg_price']['value']

#returns rows that are greater than avg value 
def rows_greater_than_avg(avg_value):
    query = json.dumps({
     "query" : {
        "range": {
            "price": {
                "gte":avg_value
              }
         }
      }
    })
    response = requests.get(URL,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER_NAME,PASSWORD), data=query)
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    return results

# main method
def main():
   avg_value = getAvg()
   print( rows_greater_than_avg(avg_value))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed aggregations inside a query. You need to first send an aggregation query to find out the average and then send a second range query using the obtained average value.

Query 1:

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "single_avg_price": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you get the average price, say it was `12.3` and use it in your second query, like this:

Query 2:

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "price": {
            "gte": 12.3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way do it in a single query ?   For eg : In SQL world , we use the following query to find average salary employee in a single join query. "select * from employee e 
 where e. salary >= ( select avg(salary) from salary );"  .. I am looking for something similar to it.

Comment: Welcome to the NoSQL world ;-)

Comment: I solved it programmatically using Python as I did not find a way using query DSL.

Comment: There is a way with DSL: run two queries :-)

Comment: Maybe for the benefits of others you can share the highlights of how you implemented this, i.e. you certainly had to somehow run two queries in order to find the average price on which to then run your range query.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Nice, but I don't see the difference with my answer, except the fact that it's implemented in Python ;-) Good job, though.