# How can I sort by a calculated value in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch as a search engine. I'm copying records from mysql to elasticsearch and when I query elasticsearch i want to calculate a value with the data in elastic and use it to sort the results

My index looks like:

```
  {
    "busquedas" : {
      "aliases" : { },
      "mappings" : {
        "coche" : {
          "properties" : {
            "coeff_e" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "coeff_r" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "desc" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "creation_date" : "1460116924258",
          "number_of_shards" : "5",
          "number_of_replicas" : "1",
          "uuid" : "N6jhy_ilQmSb6og16suZ4g",
          "version" : {
            "created" : "2030199"
          }
        }
      },
      "warmers" : { }
    }
```

}

And i want to compute a value per record like

```
myCustomOrder = (coeff_e + coeff_r) * timestamp
```

And use it to sort results

```
{
  "sort" : [
      { "myCustomOrder" : {"order" : "asc"}},
      "_score"
  ],
  "query" : {
      "term" : { ... }
  }
}
```

I know i can use groovy to compute values but I only could use it to filter like its shown in the examples

```
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 3,
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['coeff_e'].value < 0.5"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance, I'm totally newbie to elasticsearch :D

Comment: check this out >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019873/elastic-search-aggregation-with-range-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as with filtering. Take a look at this [section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting). It should be self-explanatory once you already know about scripts :-).

For the completeness sake:

```
{
    "query" : {
        ....
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc['field_name'].value * factor",
                "params" : {
                    "factor" : 1.1
                }
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```